# How to have try and catch in R?

Tags: r

I have a R code running on our server  which downloads huge set of files from S3 and stores it in local and then loads those files into a data frame and once all the processing is done as a final step it deletes all the files from the local machine . Now if a error occurs ,the execution just halts which means someone has to manually intervene ,log into the server and run `rm -rf` on the data folder . Is there a way where I can have a `try catch or a finally block` (just like how we have in Java,Python ) where even incase of failure I can assure that the data folder is deleted from the local machine .

Comment: Have you looked at `help("tryCatch")`?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) might also help